# How to prevent pine script to open new trade untill first one hits S/L

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am new to pine script (and coding in general). For a start, I managed to code some indicators, and now I am having problems with coding a strategy.  Basically the problem is that the strategy keeps opening trades and closing previous trades before it managed to hit SL. I've tried looking for answers online, and all the suggestions that I could find didn't work out. Here is the code and I would REALLY like to learn more about pine script (for now I've studied manual, youtube, and all I have fond here...).

(I have planned to code trailing stop loss also for this strategy, but for now that seems like the distant future: :( )

```
//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy2", pyramiding = 1, overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick=true)

//supertrend1 - supertrend slow
GRP1 = "ST1"
atrPeriod1 = input(12, "ATR Length1", group = GRP1)
srcInput1 = input.source(hl2, "Source1")
factor1 = input.float(3.0, "Factor1", step = 0.01, group = GRP1)

[supertrend1, direction1] = ta.supertrend(factor1, atrPeriod1)

bodyMiddle1 = plot((open + close) / 2, display=display.none)
upTrend1 = plot(direction1 < 0 ? supertrend1 : na, "Up Trend", color = color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
downTrend1 = plot(direction1 < 0? na : supertrend1, "Down Trend", color = color.red, style=plot.style_linebr)

//supertrend - medium
GRP2 = "ST2" 
atrPeriod2 = input(11, "ATR Length2", group = GRP2)
srcInput2= input.source(hl2, "Source2")
factor2 = input.float(2.0, "Factor2", step = 0.01, group = GRP2)

[supertrend2, direction2] = ta.supertrend(factor2, atrPeriod2)

bodyMiddle2 = plot((open + close) / 2, display=display.none)
upTrend2 = plot(direction2 < 0 ? supertrend2 : na, "Up Trend", color = color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
downTrend2 = plot(direction2 < 0? na : supertrend2, "Down Trend", color = color.red, style=plot.style_linebr)

// supertrend - fast
GRP3 = "ST3"
atrPeriod3 = input(10, "ATR Length3", group = GRP3)
srcInput3 = input.source(hl2, "Source3")
factor3 = input.float(1.0, "Factor3", step = 0.01, group = GRP3)

[supertrend3, direction3] = ta.supertrend(factor3, atrPeriod3)

bodyMiddle3 = plot((open + close) / 2, display=display.none)
upTrend3 = plot(direction3 < 0 ? supertrend3 : na, "Up Trend", color = color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
downTrend3 = plot(direction3 < 0? na : supertrend3, "Down Trend", color = color.red, style=plot.style_linebr)

GRP4 = "EMA1"
len1 = input.int(50, minval=1, title="Length", group=GRP4)
src1 = input(close, title="Source", group=GRP4)
offset1 = input.int(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500, group=GRP4)
out1 = ta.ema(src1, len1)
plot(out1, linewidth=2, title="EMA", color=color.silver, offset=offset1)

GRP8 = "StochRSI"
smoothK = input.int(3, "K", minval=1, group=GRP8)
smoothD = input.int(3, "D", minval=1, group=GRP8)
lengthRSI = input.int(14, "RSI Length", minval=1, group=GRP8)
lengthStoch = input.int(14, "Stochastic Length", minval=1, group=GRP8)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source", group=GRP8)

rsi1 = ta.rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)

plInput = input.float(1.5, title="P/L Ratio", step=0.1, minval=0.1)


// long entery conditions 
longConditionsStoRSI = (k > d)
longSupertrend = close > (direction2 < 0 ? supertrend2 : na)
longConditionEMA = close > ta.ema(src1, len1)

longconditions = longConditionsStoRSI and longSupertrend and longConditionEMA  

// short entery conditions
shortConditionsStoRSI = (k < d)
shortSupertrend = close < (direction2 < 0? na : supertrend2)  
shortconditionEMA = close < ta.ema(src1, len1)

shortconditions = shortConditionsStoRSI and shortSupertrend and shortconditionEMA

// long SL
longstop = (direction1 < 0 ? supertrend1 : na)
longstop := longconditions ? (direction1 < 0 ? supertrend1 : na) : longstop[1]
longprofit = close + ((close - longstop) * plInput)

// short SL
shortstop = (direction1 < 0? na : supertrend1)
shortstop := shortconditions ? (direction1 < 0? na : supertrend1) : shortstop[1]
shortprofit = close - ((shortstop - close) * plInput)

if (longconditions)
    OpenTrade :=false
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long,1, oca_type = strategy.oca.cancel)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", "Long", profit = longprofit, stop = longstop)    

if (shortconditions)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short,1, oca_type = strategy.oca.cancel)
    strategy.exit ("Exit Short", "Short", profit = shortprofit, stop = shortstop)    

plot(longstop, "LS", color = color.red, style=plot.style_line, linewidth = 5)
plot(longprofit, "LP", color = color.green, style=plot.style_line, linewidth = 5)
plot(shortstop, "SS", color = color.orange, style=plot.style_line, linewidth = 5)
plot(shortprofit, "SP", color = color.blue, style=plot.style_line, linewidth = 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

check for position with `strategy.opentrades`

```
var secondTrade = false

isFirstTrade() =>
    if not secondTrade and strategy.opentrades == 0  
        true
    else
        false

if (longconditions and (isFirstTrade() or secondTrade) )
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long,1, oca_type = strategy.oca.cancel)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", "Long", profit = longprofit, stop = longstop)    
    secondTrade := true

if (shortconditions and (isFirstTrade() or secondTrade) )
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short,1, oca_type = strategy.oca.cancel)
    strategy.exit ("Exit Short", "Short", profit = shortprofit, stop = shortstop)    
    secondTrade := true
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i edited stop loss and take profit, and used strategy.opentrades and it is now working great. it looks like i missed strategy.opentrades function when i was reading manual :) Big thanks